# Tabs icon toggle when active and inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 tabs, When one tab is active white icon should appear and when it's inactive red icon should appear.

Please refer code below:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" onclick="switchTab(event, 'openTrips')"  id="defaultOpen" >
            <span >
            <img src="../resources/images/otp-not-received -inactive.svg" class="inactive" />
            <img src="../resources/images/otp-not-received.svg"   class="activeicon" />
            </span>
            <p>
               OTP Not Received (<span id="notReceivecount"></span>)
            </p>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" onclick="switchTab(event, 'inProgressTrips')">
            <span >
            <img src="../resources/images/otp-received-inactive.svg" class="inactive"/>
            <img src="../resources/images/otp-received.svg" class="activeicon" />
            </span>
            <p> OTP Received In Progress (<span id="receivecount"></span>)</p>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" onclick="switchTab(event, 'generateInvoice')">
            <span>
            <img src="../resources/images/ready-to-invoice-inactive.svg" class="inactive" />
            <img src="../resources/images/ready-to-invoice.svg" class="activeicon"/>
            </span>
            <p>Ready for Invoice (<span id="readyForInvoiceCount"></span>)</p>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" onclick="switchTab(event, 'invoiceData')">
            <span>
            <img src="../resources/images/invoiced -inactive.svg" class="inactive" />
            <img src="../resources/images/invoiced.svg"  class="activeicon" />
            </span>
            <p>Invoiced (<span id="invoiceCount"></span>)</p>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#" onclick="switchTab(event, 'invoiceProcessedData')">
            <span >
            <img src="../resources/images/paid-inactive.svg" class="inactive"/>
            <img src="../resources/images/paid.svg"  class="activeicon"/>
            </span>
            <p>Paid/Settlement (<span id="paidCount"></span>)</p>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

JS code in ready function

```
 if($(".tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a").hasClass('active')){
           $(".tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a.active img.inactive").hide();
           $(".tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a.active img.activeicon").show();
         }else{
            $(".tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a img.inactive").show();
           $(".tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a img.activeicon").hide();
         }
```

I want to show inactive icon when a tag don't have active class, now for active tabs it's working but for inactive tabs icon is not displaying.It's checking condition for all tabs so, initially it's getting active class and it hides all the inactive icons for all tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't precisely expose how you're currently adding/removing the `active` class to the involved tabs.
Anyway I suggest you give it up, and simply add the following inside of your `$(document).ready()` function :

```
var context = $('.tabs-style-fillup nav'),
    activeIcons = $('.activeicon', context),
    inactiveIcons = $('inactive', context);
$('.nav-link', context).on(
  'click',
  function() {
    activeIcons.hide();
    $('.activeicon', this).show();
    inactiveIcons.show();
    $('.inactive', this).hide();
  }
);
// init all, activating default tab
$('#defaultOpen').click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I achieved it through css only, it's my bad i should tried before with css instead of jquery. Thanks Once again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case since you did not attach a snippet to reproduce the problem, but most probably it is.

You should change checking class to loop so that you do it for every element.

```
$(".tabs-style-fillup nav ul li a").each(function(i, e) {
    var that = $(e);
    if (that.hasClass('active')) {
        that.find("img.inactive").hide();
        that.find("img.activeicon").show();
    } else {
        that.find("img.inactive").show();
        that.find("img.activeicon").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Janiszewski this doesn't solve the issue, I think i need to use this in script where they are applying for loop